# Swipe Effect for Delete Button showing up for Notification box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How do I add a swipe left effect for user to swipe on the notification bar and shows the delete button at the end of each notification? The swiping effect is similar to the apple message when user swipe left to one of the messages, the delete button will appear. The expected effect has been attached below.

Here is the code https://codepen.io/ahhuki/pen/JjBxKRj

```
 <div class="spacer">
            <p class="header-text">Notifications</p>
        <div class="grey-box">
            <p class="grey-box-text">Today</p>
        </div>

        <div class="notification-box">
            <div class="notification-icon">
                <i class="far fa-calendar icon"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="notification-content-box">
                <p class="notification-title">Notification Name</p>
                <p class="notification-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
                    ut aliquam, purus sit amet luctus venenatis, lectus
                    magna fringilla urna.</p>
                <p class="notification-time-label">2h ago</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="notification-box">
            <div class="notification-icon">
                <i class="far fa-calendar icon"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="notification-content-box">
                <p class="notification-title">Link To Our Survey</p>
                <p class="notification-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur: </br>
                <a href="www.survey-generator.com/293/39djd" class="notification-link">
                www.survey-generator.com/293/39djd</a></p>
                <p class="notification-time-label">2h ago</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="notification-box">
            <div class="notification-icon">
                <i class="far fa-calendar icon"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="notification-content-box">
                <p class="notification-title">Notification Name</p>
                <p class="notification-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
                    ut aliquam, purus sit amet luctus venenatis, lectus
                    magna fringilla urna.</p>
                <p class="notification-time-label">2h ago</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="notification-box">
            <div class="notification-icon">
                <i class="far fa-calendar icon"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="notification-content-box">
                <p class="notification-title">Claim Status Update</p>
                <p class="notification-content">Your claim #230291 has been moved to “Under Review”
                Status... to view more go to Claims Tab.</p>
                <p class="notification-time-label">3h ago</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grey-box">
            <p class="grey-box-text">Previous</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="notification-box">
            <div class="notification-icon">
                <i class="far fa-calendar icon"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="notification-content-box">
                <p class="notification-title">Notification Name</p>
                <p class="notification-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
                    ut aliquam, purus sit amet luctus venenatis, lectus
                    magna fringilla urna.</p>
                <p class="notification-time-label">2h ago</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="notification-box">
            <div class="notification-icon">
                <i class="far fa-calendar icon"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="notification-content-box">
                <p class="notification-title">Link To Our Survey</p>
                <p class="notification-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur: </br>
                    <a href="www.survey-generator.com/293/39djd" class="notification-link">
                        www.survey-generator.com/293/39djd</a>
                </p>
                <p class="notification-time-label">2h ago</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="notification-box">
            <div class="notification-icon">
                <i class="far fa-calendar icon"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="notification-content-box">
                <p class="notification-title">Notification Name</p>
                <p class="notification-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
                    ut aliquam, purus sit amet luctus venenatis, lectus
                    magna fringilla urna.</p>
                <p class="notification-time-label">2h ago</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="notification-box">
            <div class="notification-icon">
                <i class="far fa-calendar icon"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="notification-content-box">
                <p class="notification-title">Claim Status Update</p>
                <p class="notification-content">Your claim #230291 has been moved to “Under Review”
                    Status... to view more go to Claims Tab.</p>
                <p class="notification-time-label">3h ago</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the expected effect.
[image: Swipe]

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this, using Framework7, you can achieve this effect. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/framework7/list_views_swipe_delete.htm#